# How can I replace this "if" statement with something else?

Tags: java, if-statement, polymorphism

beginner coder here. So I have this block of code:

```
public String doOperation(String s1, String s2) {
    if(s2.compareTo("") == 0) return s1;
    else return s2;
}
```

Just a rough draft, but essentially I'm saying to return s2 unless it's an empty string, then return s1 instead.
Is there any way I can accomplish this without an if statement? For the assignment, I'm not supposed to use if statements, switch statements, while loops, exception handling, or pretty much anything else that is just a sneaky way to get around an "if" statement.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this through polymorphism but I also don't want to be creating a ton of new things just to accomplish this tiny task. Any ideas/help? Thanks!

Comment: Kind of a really odd assignment...

Comment: It is, but it's supposed to teach us to use other skills we've learned about inheritance and polymorphism to not use "if" statements. Kind of a challenge. I did pretty much all of the assignment using strategy design and making lots of new classes, but for such a tiny statement as this one I really didn't want to do that much more code.

Comment: @CSteggs you can only add inheritance to a non `final class`  You could do something like this with inheritance if it was your own class.

Comment: @CSteggs, remember you can always accept the solution you found helpful. Have a look at my solution with error handling. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should consult your teacher/professor about this assignment. I perfectly understand (s)he doesn't want you to use if and switch to execute different blocks of code based on some attribute of an object (i.e. if your object is an order, don't execute if/switch based on the order's type). But checking for null and base cases (such as an empty string) should be a perfectly valid use of if.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary operator:

```
return s2.isEmpty() ? s1 : s2;
```

Comment: I think you ternary operator qualifies as a "sneaky way to get around an "if" statement" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bit of a brain teaser.. This is awful code, but should do what you want...

`return s1.substring(Math.min(s1.length()-1, s1.length() * s2.length()) + s2`

So, if s2's length is 0, you'll print s1 starting at position 0, followed by s2, which is empty

If s2's length is not 0, you'll print s1 starting at the last position (i.e. nothing) followed by s2

Oh boy, I feel dirty now :)

Comment: Is `Math.min()` considered a 'sneaky way to get around an "if"'? After all it's just wrapping `return a < b ? a : b`

Comment: he he valid point. If this were python, you could just go over the string length

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [Ternary operation](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018), super useful

```
public String doOperation(String s1, String s2) {
    return s2.compareTo("") == 0 ? s1 : s2;
}
```

Comment: I think you ternary operator qualifies as a "sneaky way to get around an "if" statement" ;)

Comment: it's quite "sneaky" indead haha @Miquel

Answer (score 1):

Since everyone else has covered the ternary (or conditional operator `? :`), you could also do it with a `switch` like

```
public String doOperation(String s1, String s2) {
    switch (s2.length()) {
    case 0: return s1;
    }
    return s2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always make sure that you handle null scenarios and exception handling first.

```
public String doOperation(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s2 == null) {
        System.out.println("Error Msg: null value");
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return s2.isEmpty() ? s1 : s2;
}
```

Update 1: For this particular scenario using `s2.isEmpty()` is slightly faster or has a better coding style when compared to `s2.equals("")`, or `s2.length() == 0`, or `s2.compareTo("") == 0`

Comment: I think it is the appropriate way that using equals method for strings comparison.

Comment: Note that `equals()` will work well for many different scenarios. However, for this particular scenario, we can make it faster by using `isEmpty()`. I will update it as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String doOperation(String s1, String s2) {
    int mask = 1 / (1 + s2.length());
    return s1.substring(0, s1.length() * mask) + s2);
}
```

The mask will be `0` for any nonempty `String` due to `integer`-arithmetic and `1` for an empty `String`, as `1 / 1 = 1`.

In the second line the `0` mask will 'nullify' the length of the substring, leaving it empty and the appended `s2` is the only thing that is returned.

On the other hand the `1` mask will not change the value of `s1.length()` and the appended `s2` is empty anyway (as we got the `1` mask), so the only thing returned is `s1` from beginning to end.